# iTunes randomly plays songs while importing, and can't be stopped

Tags: itunes

I'm importing a gazillion songs over the network into iTunes. Every now and then, it starts playing the song it's currently importing. And because iTunes is basically frozen up during the import process, I can't actually stop it. Then it will suddenly jump to another song a bit later on.

Pretty irritating. Is it a known issue? Anything I can do about it?

Versions (oops): iTunes 10.5 (141), OS X 10.6.8

Comment: Please include your operating system and iTunes version! :)

Comment: iTunes should not freeze during an import I think. If it does, you might have triggered a bug. Does it respond to the Play/Pause key on your keyboard (if there is one)?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this macworld article](http://www.macworld.com/article/1135501/itunes8prefs.html), do the following in Terminal, quit & relaunch iTunes

```
defaults write com.apple.iTunes play-songs-while-importing -bool FALSE
```

Comment: Interesting. That value wasn't set, and according to the article, it should default to false. I'll see what happens next time I do an import.